# matplotlib latex in legend label vs in axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

For matplotlib, you can label legends and axis labels using tex command syntax. You're *supposed* to prepend r to the string: r"my tex label". But what I don't understand is why the legend label *doesn't* care **and yet** the axis label does care.

Why do the axis labels behave differently than the legend label (or vice versa)?

MWE1 - Crashes

```
## Hello World! I crash!
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.ones(5)
plt.plot(x, x, label="$\bar{x}$ (but not really)")
plt.xlabel("$\bar{y}$ (but not really)") # I cause the crash
plt.show()
```

MWE2 - Doesn't Crash

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.ones(5)
plt.plot(x, x, label="$\bar{x}$ (but not really)") # I still don't need prepended r
plt.xlabel(r"$\bar{y}$ (but not really)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: [matplotlib docs: Rendering math equations using TeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html)

Comment: [LATEX Mathematical Symbols](https://www.caam.rice.edu/~heinken/latex/symbols.pdf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's no fair comparison. The plot label from MWE2 get's never used, because there is no legend; therefore it will not raise any error.
Once you produce this legend using `plt.legend()` it will of course cause the same kind of error that you'd expect from all other strings that contain MathText commands and are no raw strings.

**This crashes**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.ones(5)
plt.plot(x, x, label="$\bar{x}$ (but not really)") 
plt.xlabel(r"$\bar{y}$ (but not really)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
ValueError: 
$ar{x}$ (but not really)
^
Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

**This does not crash, *as all strings are raw strings***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.ones(5)
plt.plot(x, x, label=r"$\bar{x}$ (but not really)") 
plt.xlabel(r"$\bar{y}$ (but not really)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can also escape the backslash so that Python doesn't interpret `\b` as an ASCII backspace: `plt.plot(x, x, label="$\\bar{x}$ (but not really)")`